# Oracle 10g Maximum number of session expired

Tags: oracle10g

We have Oracle 10 g databse and we are getting message as ORA-00018: maximum number of sessions exceeded . we configure the parameter as below;

Session 600
process : 600

and its a shared Server Mode.  We update this to Session :900 and Process : 750.  and right now Oracle is running,but i need to know is this help us to go on or i need to do some other changes also to avoid the error "ORA-00018: maximum number of sessions exceeded"

Can anybody help plz
Your response is Highly appreciated

Regards
Joseph

Comment: Hi all Thanks . we solve this issue. Now we are removing all the inactive sessions those are idle for more than    30 minutes idle. Hope this will help you guys too.

Answer (score 1):

You may have users taking sessions and not releasing them at all, or holding them for a long time. See if there are any long-running transactions when you get that exception.

Comment: i was not able to connect when i got error .so i restart the databse,so ididnt knew who are connected long time

Comment: When it happens again, before restarting the database, see if you can retrieve any logs of the transactions. Someone may be connecting to your database and not be releasing those connections.

Comment: we solve this issue. Now we are removing all the inactive sessions those are idle for more than 30 minutes idle.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to know this is to connect to database and dump v$session table every after 5-10 minutes. In this way you can come to know that at times what all processes/applications were holding connection to the database. It could be a bug where a long running process/daemon/service which is not releasing the session at all. A simple script if you can run as a cron job to dump v$session table, it could become visible.

Comment: we solve this issue. Now we are removing all the inactive sessions those are idle for more than 30 minutes idle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it, for a 12c database:

**1** Control the number of connections in use

Loggin in your PDB

```
sqlplus <username>/<pswd>@<hostname>:1521/<ServiceName>
```

Check the number of connections

```
SELECT
    'Currently, ' 
    || (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION)
    || ' out of ' 
    || VP.VALUE 
    || ' connections are used.' AS USAGE_MESSAGE
FROM 
    V$PARAMETER VP
WHERE 
    VP.NAME = 'sessions'
```

It displays “Currently n out of m connections are used.” Here n > m. It should be the opposite.

**2** Change the max number of sessions

Loggin as sys in your PDB

```
quit
sqlplus / as sysdba
alter session set container = PDB1;
```

Change the number of sessions

```
alter system set sessions=100 scope=both sid='*';
```

**3** Bounce the database

```
SQL> shutdown immediate
SQL> startup
```

Open all the PDBs (closed by the bouncing)

```
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL OPEN;
```

**4** Control again

```
sqlplus <username>/<pswd>@<hostname>:1521/<ServiceName>
```

Run the control SQL query

```
SELECT
    'Currently, ' 
    || (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION)
    || ' out of ' 
    || VP.VALUE 
    || ' connections are used.' AS USAGE_MESSAGE
FROM 
    V$PARAMETER VP
WHERE 
    VP.NAME = 'sessions'
```

It displays “Currently n out of m connections are used.” Now n < m.